# Solr ClusteringComponent Carrot2: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: solr, wildfly, carrot2

I am trying to upgrade wildfly from 9 to 24 and on startup of server I am getting below exception related to **org.carrot2**

```
Descriptor class not found: org.carrot2.source.solr.SolrDocumentSourceTestDescriptor
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.util.attribute.BindableDescriptorUtils.getDescriptorClass(BindableDescriptorUtils.java:77)
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.util.attribute.BindableDescriptorUtils.getDescriptor(BindableDescriptorUtils.java:92)
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.util.attribute.BindableMetadata.forClassWithParents(BindableMetadata.java:62)
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.util.attribute.BindableDescriptorBuilder.buildDescriptor(BindableDescriptorBuilder.java:69)
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.util.attribute.BindableDescriptorBuilder.buildDescriptor(BindableDescriptorBuilder.java:47)
    at deployment.test.war//org.carrot2.core.ProcessingComponentDescriptor.onCommit(ProcessingComponentDescriptor.java:326)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103
```

I have checked it with updating relevant dependencies but it won't help to fix the issue.
I have checked it that without any changes it works fine with wildfly-24 and jdk-8 but won't work with java 21 or java 11

Also ask in jboss community. Please check link :
https://lists.jboss.org/archives/list/jbosstools-dev@lists.jboss.org/message/V6DSICRHCAKTXEZMX55KYCLNDJYLGURD/

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I found the solution and it works fine now. It was due to java upgrade from 8 to 21 and due to that it was not processing annotations which we need to do manually which has fixed the issue.